# Is it bad practice to add methods to a class outside of the class?

Tags: python, python-3.x

For example, I have a class `Foo` that I do not have access to the source of (specifics are unimportant).

```py
class Foo:
    def __init__(self):
        self.x: int = 0
```

I want to extend this class, adding a new explicit constructor, I understand the typical way to do this is

```py
class Foo(Foo):
    @staticmethod
    from_x(x: int) -> 'Foo':
        foo = Foo()
        foo.x = x
        return foo
```

is it a bad idea to do something like the below? If so, why?

```py
@staticmethod
def __Foo_from_x(x: int) -> 'Foo':
    foo = Foo()
    foo.x = x
    return foo
Foo.from_x = __Foo_from_x
del __Foo_from_x
```

The reason could be something as simple as 'the first is stylistically cleaner', but I am more interested in the differences between the two implementations for a user of my extended class.

Comment: Scoping? The `if` statement doesn't create a new scope.

Comment: The constructor should probably be a class method, not a static method. I'm not sure why you are trying to do your own name-mangling here.

Comment: (You can simply use `del from_x` after making the assignment to clean up the global namespace.)

Comment: You can use a function to accomplish the scoping you want: `Foo = add_constructor(Foo)`, with `add_constructor` defining and assigning the class method in its local scope.

Answer (score 0):

If there is no specific reason to define a method not inside of the class definition it would be preferred to keep everything together. So it is definitely better to define your method in your class to provide better readability of your code. Especially if other persons will have to work with your code it could be harder to find the definition of it (even if it's just to understand what is happening).

Another thing I noticed in you code is the line:
`if True: # for scoping`
You should keep in mind, that an if-statement does not come with its own scope, these belong to methods, classes and modules. So your if-statement does not provide any functionality.

Comment: The `if True` was removed from the original post